# i want to build an android app to communicate with raspberry pi 3?

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to create an Android app that can send a confirmation message, over WiFi to my raspberry pi3 connected to the same WiFi network. How can I achieve this task?

The raspberry pi is running on raspbian. what i need to do??

Comment: Try googling "android network communication".

Comment: Hey bud, why don't you make life simple connect your Raspberry PI to the internet. Then let the PI send you the confirmation message using the internet :)

Comment: You need a server application on your raspi and a client app on your Android device. Nothing special.

Comment: that what i need but i need help to make a client app on android @greenapps

Comment: Ok. You can get all the help you want here. Come on with your questions!

Comment: thanks @greenapps ..

first i want to know which i should make it as a server raspberry pi or android ??  and i think raspberry it will be work as a server.
. 
so what should i learn to build a client android app ???

Comment: Yes. Good idea to make the raspi the server. Ok. Now first decide what kind of server as you cannot start making a client when you dont know the server type.

Comment: @greenapps could you recommend a server working in both android and raspberry ??

Comment: Nonsense. That server only has to function on the raspberry. On the Android you need a client.

Comment: how to write a client program on android ?? do you have a sample ?@greenapps

Comment: You still did not tell what kind of server you are going to use.

Comment: @greenapps can i chat with you ??

Comment: No. I see no reason.